# PHP Script Not Downloading A Zipped Product Feed From URL - Download works fine when visited on browser

Tags: php, download, copy, zip, feed

I have a simple bit of PHP code which copies a zip file from a remote url to the server, and then extracts it into another folder.

```html
function extract_remote_zip($new_file_loc, $tmp_file_loc, $zip_url) {
    
    echo 'Copying Zip to local....<br>';
    
    //copy file to local
    if (!copy($zip_url, $tmp_file_loc)) {
        echo "failed to copy zip from".$zip_url."...";
    }
    
    //unzip 
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open($tmp_file_loc);
    
    if ($res === TRUE) {
        echo 'Extracting Zip....<br>';
        if(! $zip->extractTo($new_file_loc)){
            echo 'Couldnt extract!<br>';
        } 
        $zip->close(); 
        echo 'Deleting local copy....<br>';
        unlink($tmp_file_loc);
        return 1;
        
        
    } else {
        echo 'Failed to open tmp zip!<br>';
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It works perfectly with one URL from Awin and downloads and extracts the correct 600kb zip, but with another from Webgains it just downloads a Zip file with size 0 bytes. I'm guessing the download is getting corrupted somewhere?

When I visit the URL on my browser it downloads the zip perfectly (the size is about 3mb). I just can't get it to download with PHP.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't provide the problem URL, I can't say for sure, but you are likely encountering an issue with the method copy uses to read the file. Doing a direct curl call should resolve this.

Try the below:

```
function file_get_contents_curl( $url ) {

  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );

  $data = curl_exec( $ch );
  if ( curl_errno( $ch ) <> FALSE ) {
    echo "ERROR at line " . __LINE__ . " in file_get_contents_curl: error number: " . curl_errno( $ch ) . ' error : ' . curl_error( $ch ) . " url: $url";
    return FALSE;
  }

  curl_close( $ch );

  return $data;

}

function extract_remote_zip($new_file_loc, $tmp_file_loc, $zip_url) {

    echo 'Copying Zip to local....<br>';

    // read the zip
    if ( $zip_str = file_get_contents_curl( $zip_url ) ) {

      // write the zip to local
      if (  !file_put_contents( $tmp_file_loc, $zip_str ) ) {
        echo "failed to write the zip to: " . $zip_url;
        return FALSE;        
      }

    } else {
      echo "failed to read the zip from: " . $zip_url;
      return FALSE;
    }

    //unzip
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $res = $zip->open($tmp_file_loc);

    if ($res === TRUE) {
        echo 'Extracting Zip....<br>';
        if(! $zip->extractTo($new_file_loc)){
            echo 'Couldnt extract!<br>';
        }
        $zip->close();
        echo 'Deleting local copy....<br>';
        unlink($tmp_file_loc);
        return 1;


    } else {
        echo 'Failed to open tmp zip!<br>';
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I really need learn to use cURL!